# Cosmos DB: how to project properties into array and group them?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Using this sample data consisting of 3 separate documents in the same container:

```json
{
  "id" : "doc1",
  "manager" : "John",
  "country": "Germany"
}

{
  "id" : "doc2",
  "manager" : "John",
  "country": "Netherlands"
}

{
  "id" : "doc3",
  "manager" : "Jack",
  "country": "Austria"
}
```

I would like to write a query that returns a list of objects containing the distinct manager names and the countries they're responsible for. Something in the shape of:

```json
[
{
  "manager": "John",
  "countries": ["Germany", "Netherlands"]
},
{
  "manager": "Jack",
  "countries": ["Austria"]
}
]
```

I have tried (and failed) with joins, subqueries, and JSON object projections.

Comment: Is your sample data one array inside a document or are those three seperate documents?

Comment: Very good point. 3 documents. I updated my question.

Comment: Cosmos doesn't work this way; you can't project properties from queries that cross documents in a subquery.  You will need to do this sort of thing client-side. Pull the documents into C# (or language of choice) and manipulate as needed in memory.